# Firebase notification not launching (or launching with delay) app

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I'm sending a push notification from Firebase console to my Android App. But sometimes, after receiving the notification and waiting for a couple of hours, and clicking the notification thereafter, it is not opening the app.

**PS: In Samsung devices app is opening after a delay of 30+ seconds but in other devices like Mi or Oneplus, it is not opening at all.**

**Bug video:**

[In Samsung device](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14RkKD7fN41nWzRZFX_QtHesK-1r897N2/view?usp=sharing)

[In Mi device](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hrUhINtjGfAsjjnGUurdxg3r6hriTtIM/view?usp=sharing)

**App manifest file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.baja.app">

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<application
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    android:name=".BajaApplication"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="false"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Default"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

    <activity
        android:name=".ui.home.HomeActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:autoVerify="true"
            tools:targetApi="m">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "example://gizmos” -->
            <data
                android:host="@string/share_host"
                android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".ui.welcome.WelcomeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    <activity
        android:name=".ui.home.alarms.ringer.AlarmRingingActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance" />

    <service
        android:name=".media.MediaService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name=".messaging.BajaFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name=".ui.welcome.AddressIntentService"
        android:exported="false" />

    <service
        android:name=".media.download.InternalMediaDownloadService"
        android:exported="false" />

    <service
        android:name=".media.download.ExternalMediaDownloadService"
        android:exported="false" />

    <service android:name=".ui.home.alarms.ringer.AlarmMediaService" />

    <receiver android:name=".media.download.DownloadCancelReceiver" />

    <receiver
        android:name=".ui.home.alarms.AlarmsBroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name=".ui.home.alarms.RescheduleAlarmsService"
        android:exported="false" />

    <!--
        MediaSession, prior to API 21, uses a broadcast receiver to communicate with a
        media session. It does not have to be this broadcast receiver, but it must
        handle the action "android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON".
        Additionally, this is used to resume the service from an inactive state upon
        receiving a media button event (such as "play").
    -->
    <receiver android:name="androidx.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver> <!-- Disable crash and analytics reporting for debug builds -->

    <meta-data
        android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled"
        android:value="${enableCrashReporting}" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_deactivated"
        android:value="${disableAnalyticsReporting}" /> <!-- Set custom default icon and color for request notification -->

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
        android:value="@string/default_notification_channel" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/ic_favicon" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/black" />

    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="@string/app_fileprovider_authority"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>
</application>
```

**onMessageReceived method**

```
override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        val notification: RemoteMessage.Notification = remoteMessage.notification ?: return

        val channelId: String = notification.channelId ?: getString(R.string.default_notification_channel)
        val (channelCode: Int, @StringRes channelNameRes: Int, @StringRes channelDescRes: Int) =
            getNotificationChannelRelatedParams(channelId)

        buildAndShowNotification(
            notification.title!!,
            notification.body!!,
            channelId,
            notification.imageUrl,
            remoteMessage.data,
            channelCode,
            channelNameRes,
            channelDescRes
        )
}
```

**Notification builder method**

```
 private fun buildAndShowNotification(
        title: String,
        message: String,
        channelId: String,
        imageUri: Uri?,
        extras: Map<String, String>,
        requestCode: Int,
        @StringRes channelName: Int,
        @StringRes channelDescRes: Int
    ) {
        val defaultSoundUri: Uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)

        val intent: Intent = Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java).apply {
            addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
            extras.keys.forEach { key ->
                putExtra(key, extras[key])
            }
        }
        val pendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

        val builder: NotificationCompat.Builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_favicon)
            .setColor(Color.BLACK)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
        applyImageUrl(builder, imageUri)
        val manager: NotificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val channel = NotificationChannel(
                channelId,
                getString(channelName),
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            ).apply { description = getString(channelDescRes) }
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }

        manager.notify(requestCode, builder.build())
    }
```

**Checking notification intent in HomeActivity, if notification handled by system tray**

```
onCreate(..){
    //statements

    // Check if opened with notification
    val intentData: Triple<String, String?, Boolean> = if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        playFromIntent(intent, appLaunch = true)
    } else {
        Triple("", null, false)
    }

    //statements
}
```

Comment: is the onMessageReceived called?

Comment: No, as stated in the documentation, *Messages with both notification and data payload, when received in the background are handled by system tray and data payload is delivered in the extras of the intent*, as I'm sending both the payloads, "onMessageReceived" will not be called if the app is in background.

Comment: do the notification from the rest of the apps work as expected? Have a look at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52831526/4809922

Comment: @ElizaCamber Thanks for sharing, but as mentioned in the question, as tested in Samsung devices, there is a delay, but in other devices like Mi or Oneplus, there is no delay and overall the app is not opening.

Comment: I see those as 2 separate issues. I'd start with checking the Samsung's settings as mentioned above since at least the app is opening there. Then I'd try debugging what the onCreate is getting. Also make sure you're sending the right scheme since you're only supporting https in the Manifest

Comment: Sure. Just adding again *In Samsung (and other devices) app is opening fine, but ONLY WHEN CHANGING TIME MANUALLY OR WAITING FOR FEW HOURS the issue seems to be occurring.*

Comment: How are you sending those? A server or a cloud function? What's the behavior if you send a test notification directly from the firebase console?

Comment: I'm sending the notifications manually from FCM console. (with additional data)